# Can we issue 'iptables' commands via the '/proc' FS?

Tags: iptables, proc

I have an embedded Linux platform that is heavily stripped down.  It does not have the '/sbin/iptables' binary and it would be impossible (political/technical) to get it installed.  Many other tools are also stripped out, so in the past I have been able to do what I needed by manipulating the '/proc' file system.

I need to issue the following command in order to block all IP's (except 'localhost') from accessing our port:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port $PORT -s $IP_ADDR -j DROP
```

Is there a place in the proc where I can write to it in order to do simulate the 'iptables' command above?

Or maybe network config files, but then I'm guessing that would be different for several Linux platforms.

**Update - 2012.05.08**

I ended up being able to install the 'iptables' package on the device only to find out that the kernel has no support built in.  No now its a game of compiling the kernel modules (ko) and adding them in.  I'm not even sure which compile flags should be enabled other than 'CONFIG_NETFILTER'... there seems to be a ton of other ones.

Comment: there's a library you can use to write your own applications. I'd try running strace/ltrace on it on another machine and see what calls/libraries are used.

Comment: I'm guessing that since you are not naming that library which can be used to set/remove rules it's because you don't know the name.

Comment: I found this from another user's post:  http://linux.die.net/man/3/libipq, but I'm not sure if it's exactly what would be needed to add/remove rules.

Comment: I can't remember the exact one that would do that. It's part of of the netfilter code but it's what iptables links against anyway so doesn't really win you much if installing iptables wouldn't be allowed. (I think it's xtables though)

Comment: libipq is a more specialised case where you want an iptables rule that sends packets via a userspace decision process which I don't think is what you're looking for.

Comment: @awoodland Reading the libipq man page did seem to reveal that but I wasn't quite sure... thanks!

Comment: I found the following and I'm adding it for informational purposes since I don't know much about it (yet):  http://www.lowth.com/rope/ProcFileSystem.  I do intend to investigate it at some point because it's the kind of thing you'd want (at least I do).